# sed for parsing multiline

Tags: replace, sed

I am replacing one multi-line pattern:

```
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
```

using following `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's|&lt;\/p&gt;\n&lt;ul&gt;|\\begin{itemize}|g'
```

but it does not seem to be working fine. How can I replace above pattern using `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `GNU sed`, you can use a loop:

```
sed ':a; N; $!ba; s|&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;ul&gt;|\\begin{itemize}|g' file
```

For `BSD/OSX sed`, try:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's|&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;ul&gt;|\\begin{itemize}|g' file
```

---

As per comments, simply add in the spaces at the beginning of each line:

```
sed ':a; N; $!ba; s| *&lt;/p&gt;\n *&lt;ul&gt;|\\begin{itemize}|g' fileg
```

Comment: @user15662: What version of `sed` are you using? On a simple test file, the above is working under `GNU sed` as stated.

Comment: Ok in my case there are few spaces before new line. How can i handle them

Comment: Ubuntu should ship with `GNU sed`. You can type `sed --version | head -n 1` to make sure.

Comment: your command is working fine with newline but my file has some spaces after newline. For that i m using sed ':a; N; $!ba; s|&lt;/p&gt;\n(\s)*&lt;ul&gt;|\\begin{itemize}|g' file but not desired output.

Comment: @user15662: Perhaps it would be worthwhile adding a good amount of sample input and desired output to your question. Without seeing your inputs, it's very hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish.